# Congruence with Lucas sequence

Tags: number-theory

I want to show that for each $n \geq 2$ the following congruence holds,

$$L_{2^n} \equiv 7 \pmod{10}.$$

According to my notes,

$$L_n=\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$

and
$$L_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1},$$

where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Do we use somehow the last equality in order to show the desired congruence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following helps :
$$L_{2n}=L_n^2-2(-1)^n\tag1$$
(the proof is written at the end of the answer.)

---

This is a proof by induction.

For $n=2$, $L_{2^2}=7\equiv 7\pmod{10}.$

Suppose that $L_{2^n}=10k+7$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$.

Then, using $(1)$, we get
$$\begin{align}L_{2^{n+1}}&=L_{2^n}^2-2(-1)^{2^n}
\\\\&=(10k+7)^2-2
\\\\&=10(10k^2+14k+4)+7
\\\\&\equiv 7\pmod{10}\end{align}$$

---

*Proof for $(1)$* :

Using that $L_{n}=\alpha^n+\beta^n$ where $\alpha=\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$, we get
$$L_{2n}-L_n^2=\alpha^{2n}+\beta^{2n}-(\alpha^n+\beta^n)^2=-2(\alpha\beta)^n=-2(-1)^n$$

Comment: I see... @mathlove Thanks a lot!!!